# Very Low performance with 500 agents with A* Pathfinding Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, a-star

I am using A* pathfinding and behaviour manager for AI system in my game and using 500 agents just patrolling around the map. Is it normal? I need to increase the FPS around 60 FPS where it is around 5 now... What should I do?

After a lot of trials the profiler results are;

1) Without astar pathfinding, behaviour manager and any agent (around 2ms on main thread).
[image]

2) Without astar pathfinding and behaviour manager, only 500 agents
[image]

3) With Only astar pathfinding (without any move command) with 500 agents
[image]

4) With both astar pathfinding and behaviour manager (with patrolling command) with 500 agents
[image]

Note: I am using character controller in my agents, I tried to disable it, but the gain was negligible. Also, I disabled the fixedUpdate section in AIBase.cs().

Btw, I am using 1 single Recast graph with the following options and result. 
[image]

Comment: 1. If you use fixedupdate / rigidbody you can increase fixed timestep [Time](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html).
2. Standalone build will increase performance.
3. Buy a better PC.

Comment: You can try also ECS approach - [ECS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.0/manual/index.html)

Comment: 1) I use Update() :/  2) Standalone does not boost a lot :/ 3) I guess there is nothing to do? This is a mobile game...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splitting them between threads? Pathfinding algorithms are computationally intense and shouldn't be done in update.